# I have made changes to my asset framework by deleting the database can restore it

Tags: osisoft

I have deleted my database from the asset framework in test is there anyway i can recover this. I know that I can use a copy of the database from the prod mode but i just want to recover the database in test, any help please

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there aren't really any special feature particular to PI AF which helps you here. You'll probably need to talk to your IT team about database recovery.

There are three possibilities:

1. If [PI AF Backups](https://livelibrary.osisoft.com/LiveLibrary/content/en/server-v6/GUID-755F43FB-A73B-4133-8479-B72562942680) are being taken, there might be an easy way to restore your database. If this is not configured presently, encourage your IT team to implement this.
2. Your IT team will probably have a backup of the SQL database used by your PI AF server. This may be difficult to restore in a useful way that gets you the last copy of your database back, but it's worth asking about.
3. As you said, you could also take a copy from the Production instance and bring it back into Dev. Take care that you adjust the Security correctly.

The fact you were able to delete the database is a little alarming, and may indicate you have Delete permissions on other databases that aren't yours - or worse, that other people can Delete your database! Please do talk to your support team about tightening up the security to avoid this in future. If it was me I'd seek a security audit for the whole system.

AF security can be tricky to implement properly - if the team is not confident in this, do encourage them to involve an OSIsoft partner organization - ideally one from the Premier Partner list if possible.